# Unexpected behaviour with output caching on IIS

Tags: performance, iis, caching, memory

I have set the output caching on IIS as per image cache setting[image: cache setting]
The result is as per image result with setting[image]
So here i am getting 2 contradicting result, the response code is 304 which means the image is not changed and should be served from cache, while if you check the tooltip it says it's transferred over the network and showing the size  and time for download.
Now when i removed the setting as per image [image: no cache set], the result as per image [image: result with no cache set]
Here the result is served either from disk cache or memory cache.
Can someone please help why i am getting those contradicting results and if there is something wrong with my setting
Thanks in advance
Nader

[image: still cached]

Answer (score 0):

You can try below setting for the client side caching:

1)Open iis , select your site

2)From the middle pane choose Http Response Header

[image]

3)Select set common headers from Action pane:

[image]

4)Check expire web content and set the value as per your requirement:

[image]

[image]

Here is the document you can get more detail about client side caching:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

and here you can find when to use iis output caching:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching#when-to-use-output-caching

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, did you add the file types in output caching option?, as now when i have the files added like what i sent in my original post, the files are not cached but when i remove the file types from it caching works !!!

Comment: regarding option to expire web content, i already have that option set

Comment: @NaderGalal  if you have already set the client caching with the response header you do not need to add the file extension in output caching.

Comment: the output caching is for the dynamic and semi dynamic content. you can refer this document for more detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching#when-to-use-output-caching

Comment: Thank you Jalpa Panchal, this means i will remove the entries i had in output caching option to let the browser cache by default, what if some files were updated, what should i do in that case ,so client gets the updated version without asking him to clear cache in the browser

Comment: Browser will automatically serve you with the updated file. but if you are going to use dynamic content you have to set the output caching to serve the updated file

Comment: I have removed all file types from output caching option and everything is cached now which is good, the issue i have now is when i update any file, the old version is still cached and i am not getting the updated one automatically as you mentioned.

Comment: From searching may posts and links, it seems the best thing is to use versioning for files, but is there any option to get the same output using IIS without any changes in code, to detect last modified date for file and compare with cached one, if not the same get the latest file instead of cached one.

Comment: @NaderGalal may I know what kind of website you are using ? and which files you are getting cached result for dynamic or static?

Comment: @NaderGalal i have test with the scenario you have mentioned, in that case you cab try to reduce the time for the caching to avoid the image not being changed after change

Comment: I am using IIS , the files i try to cache(only if not changed) are js,css,png,ico,html

Comment: I know i could use the versioning workaround to handle that, but the system is very big and this will require a major change, so i was looking to do it through an administration option

Comment: Another comment after reading the links you sent, i don't think output caching is the option i need, what i need is this("IIS automatically caches static content (such as HTML pages, images, and style sheets), since these types of content do not change from request to request. IIS also detects changes to the files when you make updates, and IIS flushes the cache as needed."), the problem i have is that when a file is changed , the client browser still gets the old cached file.

Comment: i added a new image to my original post called still cached, here i changed the file but still the browser sees last modified date as yesterday not now and gets from cache

Comment: @NaderGalal could you try setting up expire time to 1 min and make a test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252149/discussion-between-nader-galal-and-jalpa-panchal).